# Link between html-css-jQuery fail on mobile

Tags: android, html, css

My site works great on my PC and I don't have any problems.

I copied all the files (CSS, HTML, and jQuery) to my Android phone, and for some reason they will not interact with each other (no design or jumping between htmls).

They are all in the same main folder and nothing has changed. I tried with few different browser and it just won't work.

I have also looked online and I find many answers asking to use :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

So I have it, and it still won't fix it. please help!

Comment: Could you post the link to your website?

Comment: what do you mean "copied the files to your android phone" ??? Also, please post some of the header code so we can see how you wrote your dependencies

Comment: My website is local, I didn't upload it to the internet ..
I mean that i drag the folder that includes the .CSS .JS .HTML with resources to my android phone, and it does show the html on the browser, but the file will not interact between each other

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png">
 <title>Mט Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>